# Работа с формами VC++

Tags: visual-c++, c++-cli, forms

Необходимо, чтобы при нажатии на buton3 закрывалась форма.
Нашел код, но он не работает. Пожалуйста, подскажите, что не так?

```
private: System::Void button3_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
         MessageBox->Show("This program will close");
         Form1->Close();
}
```

Comment: Как именно не работает этот код?

Comment: "во время построения проэкта возникли ошибки...". После компиляции при нажатии на кнопку ничего не происходит.

Comment: error C2143: синтаксическая ошибка: отсутствие ";" перед "->"

Comment: Это называется "не собирается", а не "не работает". Текст сообщений об ошибках нужно добавить в сам вопрос. И сдается мне это еще и не единственная ошибка сборки у вас...

Comment: только эта ошибка

Comment: в рядке с massage box и следующем за ним

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вместо

```
Form1->Close();
```

напишите просто

```
this->Close();
```

или

```
Form1::Close();
```

или

```
Close();
```

Что касается `MessageBox`, то правильно следует написать

```
MessageBox::Show("This program will close");
```

Вот как может выглядеть метод

```
private: System::Void exitButton_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
            MessageBox::Show("This program will close");
            Form1::Close();
         }
```

Comment: спасибо работает, но только. когда я убрал  рядок                           MessageBox->Show("This program will close");

Comment: а если оставлять massage box, что тогда надо исправлять?

Comment: @Muscled Boy Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.

Comment: извините, был не внемательный. но messageBox не віскакивает все равно

Comment: error C2065: button2_Click: необъявленный идентификатор
1>c:\documents and settings\admin\мои документы\visual studio 2010\projects\forms\forms\Form1.h(82): error C3350: System::EventHandler: для конструктора делегата требуется 2 аргументов

Comment: @Muscled Boy Это у вас ошибка, не связанная с MessageBox/ Я показал, как надо вызывать MessageBox. Вставьте его перед вызовом метода Close.

Comment: я понял эта ошибка касаеться, buton 2

Comment: message box все равно не віскакивает

Comment: Все работает, просто надо было перезапустить проект

Comment: еще один вопрос, а какая разница между "::" и "->" єто ведь одно и тоже, только "::" используеться больше в c#?

Comment: @Muscled Boy Если вы имеете в виду MessageBox, то Show - это статический метод этого класса. То есть MessageBox - это не указатель на объект, а имя класса.